# Failed to install pyorc on alpine docker container

Tags: python, docker, compiler-errors, alpine-linux, orc

Getting compilation error - which is dependent on ORC binaries.

```
In file included from src/_pyorc/_pyorc.cpp:1:
src/_pyorc/Reader.h:7:10: fatal error: 'orc/OrcFile.hh' file not found
#include "orc/OrcFile.hh"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

If I compile **apache-orc** separately then too, how can I give reference of it to PyOrc Pip Installation?

Anyone has any solution or idea how can we install **pyorc** package inside alpine container.

I'm having trouble with alpine image with ubuntu and normal python docker image its working well.

Docker Image: `FROM python:3.7-alpine`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Docker multi-stage builds:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.7.3
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install pyorc -t .

FROM python:3.7.3-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ musl-dev gcompat
COPY --from=0 /app .
```

and it seems working:

```
$ docker build -t test .
$ docker run -it --rm test python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jun 27 2019, 22:53:21)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyorc
>>>
>>> with open("./new_data.orc", "wb") as data:
...     with pyorc.Writer(data, "struct<col0:int,col1:string>") as writer:
...         writer.write((1, "ORC from Python"))
...
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("./new_data.orc").read_bytes()
b'ORC\x1d\x00\x00\n\x0c\n\x04\x00\x00\x.....'
```

Comment: Yes, to be specific my problem is I have to use Alpine-Python3 not the python:3.7.3 i.e. FROM python:3.7-alpine

Answer (score 1):

Author **Noirello**, has given me the guidelines/direction as below:

For Alpine, have to install it from source.
There are some instructions in the docs how to do it: [pyOrc-Docs](https://pyorc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#install-from-source)

I'd use a multi-staged Dockerfile to build pyorc, then install the wheel into a clean Alpine image with the rest of your application.

### Something like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine AS builder
RUN apk add gcc g++ musl-dev cmake make
ARG VERSION=0.3.0

RUN mkdir build
WORKDIR /build
RUN pip install pybind11 wheel
RUN pip download --no-binary :all: --no-deps pyorc==${VERSION} && tar -xvf *.tar.gz
RUN cd pyorc-${VERSION} && python3 setup.py build_orc
RUN cd pyorc-${VERSION} && python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

FROM python:3.8.3-alpine
ARG VERSION=0.3.0

COPY --from=builder /build/pyorc-${VERSION}/dist/pyorc-${VERSION}-*.whl /tmp/
# Adding libstdc++, because the wheel expects that the libstdc++.so is presented on the system.
# Adding tzdata, because the ORC C++ lib needs to have a localtime set.
RUN apk add libstdc++ tzdata
# Setting localtime to UTC.
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime
RUN pip install /tmp/pyorc-${VERSION}-*.whl && rm -rf /tmp/pyorc-${VERSION}-*.whl
# Rest of your custom image...
```